# Without using fallback and receive function?

Tags: token, solidity, remix

I writing a token smart contract includes buy,sell and transfer function. Once at least one token was bought, the tokenPrice doubled. Assume the tokenPrice is 5 wei now, someone bought 1 token. Then I changed the tokenPrice to 10 wei. When the seller wants to sell the token back to the contract, the contract only has 5 wei, how to make the contract's funds always suffice to make the sellToken transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are trying to do is a little bit tricky. If you let users buy at (for example) 5 wei = 1 token, and immediately let them resell that token at 10 wei it won't be consistent. I would suggest maybe making the sell function lower the price by 5 wei as well. If you don't want to lower the price, you will have to cover every extra wei sold, if not, it won't be possible.

Comment: Then is it possible that the owner of the token (me) transfer ETH to the contract from my personal account when the fund is not enough?

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by "cover every extra wei sold"?

Comment: You would have to manually transfer ETH to the contract. But if at the moment of for ex. selling tokens, there is not enough ether in the contract balance, it will throw an error.

Comment: What I mean by covering every extra Wei sold is that, if, for example, a user buys 1 token at 4 wei, and then sells it at 8 Wei, and the contract only has a balance of 4 wei due to the only token bought, and supposing that the contract hasn't been prefunded with ether, it will throw an error due to insufficient ether balance.

Comment: Okay. Thank you, it seems I have to send some ETH before change the price.